# How to delete all associated records of Specific record using loop? (not Using dependent)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

How to delete all associated records of Specific record using a loop?
   like When I will delete one Specific Seller at that time their related record should be deleted. 
eg. when One Seller is deleted that time their Products, Customer, SellerMarketplace should be deleted.(Not Marketplace should be deleted.)

```
class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :products
    has_many :customers
    has_many :seller_marketplaces
    has_many :marketplaces through: :seller_marketplaces
end
```

Comment: I think you need to set the association for `seller_marketplaces` as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model should be : -

```
class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :products
    has_many :customers
    has_many :seller_marketplaces
    has_many :marketplaces through: :seller_marketplaces
end
```

Lets say you get one seller

```
  def destroy
    seller = Seller.find(params[:id])
    products = seller.products
    customers =  seller.customers
    seller_marketplaces = seller.seller_marketplaces
    if seller.destroy
      #delete products
      products.each do |product|
        product.destroy
      end
      #delete customers
      customers.each do |customer|
        customer.destroy
      end
      #delete seller_marketplaces
      seller_marketplaces.each do |mp|
        mp.destroy
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: and why not use `seller.products.destroy_all` & `seller.customers.destroy_all`

Comment: @DeepakMahakale Hi , requirement to destroy through loop. so i did not use  `seller.customers.destroy_all`

Comment: yup. sonds ok. And i think it's **He** :D

Comment: @DeepakMahakale, i'm bit confuse how to destroy seller_marketplaces, as he did not mentioned  `has_many: seller_marketplaces` so how can i destroy also `seller_marketplaces` could you point me out sir?

Comment: @DeepakMahakale if i m correct it should be `has_many: seller_marketplaces` and  `has_many :marketplaces through: :seller_marketplaces` am i right?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. He must have `has_many: seller_marketplaces` then only he can use `has_many :marketplaces through: :seller_marketplaces`

Comment: Maybe he didn't copied it properly or he hasn't set the associations properly

Comment: You cannot destroy Seller directly using destroy bcoz other records are depends on other....... So you should delete records sequentially and after that, you can delete Seller... Am I right ???

Answer (score 0):

You can use after_destroy callback

```
class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :products
 has_many :customers
 has_many :seller_marketplaces
 has_many :marketplaces through: :seller_marketplaces
 after_destroy :destroy_related_records

 def destroy_related_records
  #delete products
  products.each do |product|
    product.destroy
  end

  #delete customers
  customers.each do |customer|
    customer.destroy
  end

  #delete seller_marketplaces
  seller_marketplaces.each do |seller_marketplace|
    seller_marketplace.destroy
  end
 end
end
```